# IE 11 is throwing an error in console in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11

I have created an Angular 4 application using MVC, VS 2015.

When i browse the application on chrome it works fine but on IE 11 it is throwing below exception: -

```
XHR error:  (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost/src/main.js
Instantiating http://localhost/src/main.js
Loading src/main.js
```

my tsconfing.json is: -

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

folder structure

```
src
->app folder
main.ts
system.config.js
tsconfig.js
```

Please let me know if you have faced similar kind of issue.

Comment: can you please paste your pollyfill.ts code here?

Comment: @SandipJaiswal, I don't have pollyfill.ts file.

Comment: Can you manually browse `http://localhost/src/main.js` in IE11?

Comment: Does it make sense to still support IE in 2018?

Comment: @Fenton, yes i can open.

Comment: Thanks for answering that. How are you loading the module?

Comment: @Fenton, ai have updated folder structure in question

Answer (score 0):

You must uncomment polyfills IE lines on polyfill.ts file then run again your server